# Objective-Cで写真を切り取るライブラリを探しています。

Tags: ios, objective-c

フォトライブラリから写真を取り込み、任意の四角形で切り取れるようにしたいです。

下の画像は、「アンサー」というアプリで
プロフィール画像を変更する時によばれる画面です。

右下に選択ボタン、左下にキャンセルボタン、
ピンチで画像の拡大、スワイプで画像位置の変更ができるというUIになっています。

プロフィール画像を設定する必要のある他のアプリでも、ほぼ同じようなUIが採用されていましたので、このような機能を実現するライブラリが存在するのではないかと予想しています。
知っている方がいれば、ご教示ください。

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> プロフィール画像を設定する必要のある他のアプリでも、ほぼ同じようなUIが採用されていましたので、このような機能を実現するライブラリが存在するのではないかと予想しています。

この質問について言えば、特定のライブラリではなく、`UIImagePickerController`に`allowsEditing`を設定した場合のOS標準の挙動だと思います。

320x320の正方形でしか切り抜けないなど制約があり、より複雑なニーズに対応するために様々なライブラリがありますが、プロフィール画像の作成などであれば標準機能でも十分な場合があります。

Comment: imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true;
とコードを一行加えただけで添付画像と全く同じ動作を確認できました。特定のライブラリかと思いきや、UIKitに標準搭載されていたとは驚きです。灯台下暗しですね。教えていただきありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2):

iOS 8以上で使えるなら https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController もオススメです。